# Merge List of Dictionary using ansible

Tags: json, list, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to merge two list of dictionaries.

```
"my_name": 
[ {
"name": "xyz",
"number": "123" },
{
"name": "abc",
"number": "456"
}
]


"my_address":
[ {
"name": "abc",
"address": "smith street" },
{
"name": "xyz",
"number": "ray street"
}
]
```

Required Output:

merged:

```
[ {
"name": "abc",
"address": "smith street",
"number": "456" },
{
"name": "xyz",
"address": "ray street",
"number": "123"
}
]
```

I tried using `combine` but it would just combine the last item.

```
set_fact:
  merged: "{{ my_name | combine(my_address) }}"

"merged":
[
{
"name": "xyz",
"number": "ray street",
"number": "123"
}
]
```

i used the debug module. debug: msg: "{{ my_name| list_mergeby(my_address,'name')}}" The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'lists_mergby,

Comment: Does [Merging two dictionaries by key in Ansible](https://serverfault.com/a/1084164/448950) answer your question?

Comment: `Also used lists_mergeby but does not work either` <= [please define "does not work"](/help/mre) in an [edit] to your question because this is exactly the filter you need (as demonstrated in the duplicate answer above) and no one can guess how you used it and what result you got instead of the one you expect.

Comment: Hi @U880D i tried the solution but it did not work for me.

Comment: Hi Zeitounator i used the debug module.                                                                                                        debug:                                                                                                                                                               
    msg: "{{ my_name| list_mergeby(my_address,'name')}}"                                                                         The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'lists_mergby,

Comment: @Rtx what was unclear in my comment when I took the precaution to ask you to [edit] your question? Please see [what comments are (not) for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). That being said, the error message is crystal clear: the filter is not found and you need to install the [`community.general` collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/general)

Comment: If you expect `"address": "ray street"` in the output you should put `"address": "ray street"` into the `my_address` instead of `"number": "ray street"`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the fixed *my_address*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_name:
      - name: xyz
        number: '123'
      - name: abc
        number: '456'

    my_address:
      - name: abc
        address: smith street
      - name: xyz
        address: ray street

    merged: "{{ [my_name, my_address]|community.general.lists_mergeby('name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: merged
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  merged:
  - address: smith street
    name: abc
    number: '456'
  - address: ray street
    name: xyz
    number: '123'
```

See: the filter [*community.general.lists_mergeby*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lists_mergeby_filter.html)